# How to access fields attached to taxonomy term in views-view-field.tpl.php?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

A vocabulary has an additional field field_information attached. In a view i just want to render this information field exclusively (without term name etc). In my views-view-field.tpl.php I did a `dpm($field)`, but I can't figure out how to get to the value of field_information.
Unfortunately due to my setup I can't use the module [taxonomy_field_formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_field_formatter), I'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Puh, finally I found a way.
This is my template file views-view-field.tpl.php (instead of a custom field I used the description field, but that doesn't matter in this case):

```
<?php
if (isset($row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_myfiled['und'][0]['tid'])) {
  $tid = $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_myfield['und'][0]['tid'];
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  $output = $term->description_field['und'][0]['value'];
} else {
  $output = $output;
};
?>

<?php print $output; ?>
```